# Trying to Search by id then display data in gridview but getting syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could some please explain why I am getting this error? I am aware my code has no security but this is not for public access. Please could you explain where I am going wrong? I want to search by id then display data in gridview. I have linked the gridview with data.

**Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'EquipmentRegister''. **Line: 53 is highlighted in source error**

**Source Error:**

```
    Line 51:         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, con);
    Line 52:         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Line 53:         da.Fill(ds);
    Line 54:         gvRegister.DataSource = ds;
    Line 55:         gvRegister.DataBind();
```

Here is the apsx file:

```
private void rep_bind()
    {
        string theConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EquipRegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(theConnectString);
        string queryString = ("SELECT * EquipmentRegister WHERE EngineerRef like '" + txtEngRef.Text + "%'");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(theConnectString, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        gvRegister.DataSource = ds;
        gvRegister.DataBind();

    }


    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string theConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EquipRegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(theConnectString);
        string queryString = ("SELECT EngineerRef from EquipmentRegister  WHERE EngineerRef like'" + txtEngRef.Text + "%'");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryString,con);
        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();
            rep_bind();
            gvRegister.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            gvRegister.Visible = false;

        }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'EquipmentRegister'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789294
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340642
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +88
   ViewRegister.rep_bind() in c:\Users\Michelle\Desktop\COMF510_65300_HS_task_2\ViewRegister.aspx.cs:53
   ViewRegister.btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Michelle\Desktop\COMF510_65300_HS_task_2\ViewRegister.aspx.cs:77
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628614
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: 1.  If you haven't already, please learn about SQL Injection and how to use parameterized queries to avoid it.  2.  What is the value in `txtEngRef.Text`?

Comment: have you tried using a breakpoint and walking through (hovering over variables) to see if it's loading `dr` correctly?  have you double checked your SQL to make sure there are supposed to be rows with that call?

Comment: something that i was taught when writing SQL was to have their special words (`SELECT FROM WHERE LIKE` etc) in all caps for ease of reading.  I also create my calls in SQL first, then bring it over to Visual Studio (this is just want I do, others do it differently).  For me, I can test the call with the exact variables I expect, so I know that my SQL will be right.  I'm fairly new to web development too, these are just a few things that I do that might help you in the beginning stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sqlDataAdapter is initialized with the connectionString instead of the query. This is the reason you get an sql exception.
Use the constructor that recieves an SqlCommand instead.

Also, you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: I am new with this programming language, i changed it to queryString and it came up with same error in a different place: Incorrect syntax near 'EquipmentRegister'.

Comment: Well, First this means that this problem is fixed, since you don't get an error on that row. please edit your question to include the stack trace of the new error.

Comment: Just realised I've missed out 'From' from the query could this be throwing error?

Comment: Ok so error is no more. Thank you for your guidance.  The issue now is it hits 'else' :( why wont this work!! Thank you I will mark answer for this :)